# Can the "unearned" badges tab exclude unavailable badges, or can we get an "available" tab?

Tags: feature-request, badges

If we visit the [`/badges`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page, we will be directed to a list of *all* the badges on SO.

Looking through those badges, you will see some that are no longer possible to earn:

[image]

We currently have these tabs:

[image]

Can we also get an "available" tab to the right of the "all "tab?

Seeing badges that are impossible to earn irks me - it's as if they're taunting me. Having a page with only the available badges will placate me and hopefully others.

---

Alternatively, maybe the "unearned" tab should exclude badges that are impossible to earn. That would be a simpler solution, though it changes the definition of "unearned."

Comment: Dupe?  [Hide or group unachievable badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344183/674039)

Comment: Though my request is different, yes you're absolutely right! This is a dupe

Comment: I posted my suggestions as an answer on the parent question if anyone is interested in supporting or criticizing them.

Answer (score 2):

We can temporarily hide unavailable badges with this script that can be run in the console, and can be easily converted into [a userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-userscripts/blob/master/HideUnavailableBadges.user.js):

```
// Badges that are currently no longer available on SO
const unavail = [892, 30, 3108, 1306, 6157, 6158, 7358];

// For matching the badge URLs in the next line below
const regexp = new RegExp('\/' + unavail.join('|') + '\/');

// Remove each row where the badge is not earned and is no longer available
$('.badge').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('.badge-cell-large').find('.badge-earned-check').length == 0 && regexp.test(this.href);
}).parents('.badge-row').remove();

// Remove parent row groups without badges
$('.badge-hierarchy').filter((i,el) => el.children.length == 0).remove();
```

Once installed, the userscript will hide unavailable badges on the "Unearned" tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned

Comment: Note, these constants are exclusive for main SO. They change for meta SO and for any other site.

Comment: Hence the userscript currently only works on that specific page on SO

Comment: Hence I warn users from other sites that this would not work OOTB on those sites. SO doesn't exist in the vacuum despite what a group of users want to think.